# Another way to write a labelled function?

Tags: javascript

Is there another way to write a labelled function.
I don't understand when we use colon:

```
check**:** function(element){
            let id=element.id.split('');
            if(id[id.length-1]==this.questions[this.index].answer){
                this.score++;
                element.className="correct";
                this.scoreCard();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not labelled.

[Labels are used to navigate loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

What you have is a key in an object and the function is then an object property

```
const myObject = {
  someKey : "someValue",
  myObjectFunction: function() {}
};
```

Alternative

```
const myObject = {
  someKey : "someValue"
};

myObject["myObjectFunction"] = function() {};
```